# local area connection doesn't have a valid ip configuration

Tags: internet-connection, network-adapter

I get the following error after running diagnostic tool:
local area connection doesn't have a valid ip configuration
then I ran `ipconfig \all` in cmd and got the following:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Windows IP Configuration
   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : PE...
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : tt...
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : tt...

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B8-CA-3A-A6-12-FF
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.194.242(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 5C-F3-70-60-3F-42
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{002EE2C7-C4DF-471C-B467-49764A07C82D}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{704C200B-CB35-423C-BBB0-31A54CC32D66}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get an address within 169.254.0.0/16, then you need to first start with the basics:

1. Ensure that the Ethernet cable is plugged in securely on both sides and that you have link lights.
2. Check the arp table and see if your router is present.
3. Lastly, you can monitor DHCP traffic and look for any errors using windump or wireshark.

That address is definitely valid - just not in the way you are expecting. It means that the adapter is set for DHCP, but there is no DHCP conversation - so that address is sort of like a default network setup supplied by your OS so that you can still connect without the presence of a router (that is oversimplified, see [RFC 3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927)).

Comment: The cable is connected for sure. I checked the arp table but I don't really know what it is and how to deal with it. All i know is that all entries are static (none is dynamic as in my other computers). And finally, I downloaded wireshark but I can't figure out how to use it to monitor DHCP.